# Получение котировок binance через power query

Tags: jquery

Необходимо получить данные свечей `klines` по монетам, которые указаны в табличке *Excel* на отдельном листе. Всю инфу по `klines` разместить по колонкам (цена открытия, цена закрытия и тд).

Одна монета - одна строка. Вторая монета - вторая строка, и т.д.

[image: 1]

Есть вот такой код. Как его довести до ума не могу понять.

```
let
    Источник = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/klines?symbol=XRPUSDT&interval=15m&limit=10")),
    #"Преобразовано в таблицу" = Table.FromList(Источник, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Развернутый элемент Column1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Преобразовано в таблицу", "Column1")
in
    #"Развернутый элемент Column1"
```

Comment: Да я уже голову сломал в этом вопросе((

Comment: Реально все очень просто для того кто шарит в SQL.

Comment: Конечно пробовал. Да конечно все пересмотрел по бинансу. Вот простые 2 строки кода по битриксу. Но как сделать на бинанс не понимаю

Comment: let
    Источник = Table.FromRecords(Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries"))[result]),
    #"Измененный тип" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Источник,{{"Created", type datetime}, {"MarketName", type text}, {"High", type number}, {"Low", type number}, {"Volume", type number}, {"Last", type number}, {"BaseVolume", type number}, {"TimeStamp", type datetime}, {"Bid", type number}, {"Ask", type number}, {"OpenBuyOrders", Int64.Type}, {"OpenSellOrders", Int64.Type}, {"PrevDay", type number}})
in
    #"Измененный тип"

Comment: не по теме  но buy и sell не int а float, поставил плюс ...сам трейдингом занимаюсь ...